# Core data save not persisting

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence

I am trying to remove an item from my UICollectionView. The item is also saved using CoreData. Removing the item seems to work until I reload the view or restart the app. Both of which call `getCards` below. When that happens I the item is back and even in the Core Data database it seems the object has not been removed.

Code:

```
    -(void)removeCard:(int)position{
    UserModel *selectedUser = [self getSelectedUserFromDB];

    CardModel *cardToRemove;
    for(CardModel *cardmodel in selectedUser.cards){
        if(cardmodel.position.intValue == position){
            cardToRemove = cardmodel;
            break;
        }
    }
    int positionOldCard = cardToRemove.position.intValue;
    [selectedUser removeCardsObject:cardToRemove];
    NSMutableArray *cards = [selectedUser.cards.array mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"CARDSCOUNT: %d", cards.count);
    //This changes the position of the cards to accomodate the removing of cards above
    for(CardModel *cardmodel in cards){
        if(cardmodel.position.intValue >  positionOldCard){
            [cardmodel setPosition:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(cardmodel.position.intValue - 1)]];
            [selectedUser replaceObjectInCardsAtIndex:cardmodel.position.intValue withObject:cardmodel];
        }
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Removing the card failed %@", error);
    }

    NSLog(@"Saved cards: %d", [self getCards].count);
}
    -(NSMutableArray *)getCards{
        UserModel *selectedUser = [self getSelectedUserFromDB];
        NSMutableArray *cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(CardModel *cardModel in selectedUser.cards){
            [cards addObject:[self modelToCard:cardModel]];
        }
        NSLog(@"Loaded cards: %d", cards.count);
        return cards;
    }
```

Output:

```
2015-03-17 11:13:56.259 BeNext[3593:349310] Loaded cards: 4
2015-03-17 11:13:56.260 BeNext[3593:349310] Saved cards: 4
2015-03-17 11:13:56.271 BeNext[3593:349310] Loaded cards: 4
//RELOADING VIEW
2015-03-17 11:14:02.351 BeNext[3593:349310] Loaded cards: 5
```

Comment: You never call `[context deleteObject:cardmodel]`

Comment: Is that necessary even though I call: [selectedUser removeCardsObject]?

Comment: It depends on how your model is set up, whether you want to actually delete the card or whether you just want to clear the relationship

Comment: I want to delete the card, and you are right. If you make an answer out of this I will accept and vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the card you need to call `[context deleteObject:card model]` before you call `save` - you are manipulating the relationship but this is not the same as actually deleting the card.